# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/MessageHandlerMethodFactory

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, cqrs, spring-amqp, axon

I am going to make cqrs application using axon.I try to config axon RabbitMq to my application. If add spring-boot-starter-amqp and axon-amqp it make this error. how can I solve this.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.931 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.thamira.research.ProductServiceApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.thamira.research.ProductServiceApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/MessageHandlerMethodFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MessageHandlerMethodFactory

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   ProductServiceApplicationTests.contextLoads » NoClassDefFound org/springframew...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.136 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-07T14:26:27+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 40M/295M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project research: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/thamira/ProjectFolder/resurch/Seat_Reservation_Service/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Here is my pom.xml file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.thamira.research</groupId>
<artifactId>research</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Seat_Reservation_Service</name>
<description>research project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <axon.version>3.0.4</axon.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.axonframework/axon-amqp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>axon-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>${axon.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${axon.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I use docker instance as my rabbitmq broker.
is there any configuration need before build this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause of this error is in local old spring-messaging library different with new version. To solve this problem need to remove .m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging and re-build it.

Answer (score 6):

You have not added spring-messaging dependency. Add the following to your **pom.xml**  file (within dependencies tag)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I need <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version> because i try to use reactive

Comment: I have searched but i did not get any version as such

Comment: not yet. if i build with  <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version> it work but i need tio do with <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>